# I want old kafka event of particular id whenever I call this function. Shall I use Kafka Stream or kafkaListner

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

And which is preferred when old events are in small or large quantity. I am using spring boot

Comment: Please see [help] on asking good questions. Specifically, can you show what you've tried in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either KafkaListener or Kafka Streams, or both since they are each a Consumer function.

You need to store events somewhere to get "old" ones, such as in-memory, SQLite, H2, RocksDB, etc or other external database.

Using external, shared/networked storage would be better when you are running multiple instances of ephemeral deployments for your consumer application.

Comment: As per designer i have to use only kafka not any database

Comment: That's not possible, then. You need at least an array/map in your consumer to store "old records", which is a form of in-memory database. Obviously, the larger the records, then higher changes you will have OOM Exceptions. But, if you run two difference instances of your app, then they will only be able to get "old records" from the partitions they've been assigned in the topic, not "the most recently consumed record in the topic, over all partitions"